# Seg-faulting when trying to access a string member variable of a class - C++

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, member

Here is my HeapNode template class definition:

```
#ifndef HEAP_N

#define HEAP_N

template <class T>
class HeapNode{

public:
    // Constructor
    HeapNode(T item = T(), int new_freq = 0, int new_right = 1, 
             int new_left = 1, int new_parent = 1);

    // Accessor Functions
    T data();
    int frequency();
    int right_child();
    int left_child();
    int parent();

    // Mutator Functions
    void set_data(T item);
    void set_frequency(int new_freq);
    void set_right(int new_right);
    void set_left(int new_left);
    void set_parent(int new_parent);

    // Operators
    HeapNode operator =(const HeapNode& other);
    bool operator >(const HeapNode& other);

private:
    T datafield;    // contains the data of the node
    int freq;       // frequency
    int l_child;    // index of left child
    int r_child;    // index of right child
    int parent_;    // index of parent
};

#include "HeapNode.template"

#endif
```

And these are the mutator and accessor functions respectively:

```
template <class T>
void HeapNode<T>::set_data(T item){
    datafield = item;
}

template <class T>
T HeapNode<T>::data(){
    return(datafield);
}
```

Here is the function that makes the function calls:

```
void insert_or_update(string value, Heap<HeapNode<string> >& heap){ 

    HeapNode<string> temp;
    temp.set_data(value);
    temp.set_frequency(1);

        string ex = temp.data(); // The seg fault actually occurs in the find() function below, but any attempt to get temp.data() seg faults so the location is irrelevant

    if(!heap.empty()){  
        int index = heap.find(temp);
        if(index != -1){
            heap.inc_frequency(index);          
        }
        else{
            heap.insert(temp);
        }
    }
    else{
        heap.insert(temp);
    }   
}
```

The seg fault occurs at the

```
string ex = temp.data();
```

line.

These functions work for non-string objects, but seg fault when I use a string (constant strings and variable strings, both).

I tried using implementing the

```
datafield = item;
```

line using a copy constructor:

```
datafield = T(item);
```

but that didn't work either.
Neither did passing by reference, nor setting

```
datafield
```

to be a public member and changing it directly.

NOTE: This must compile on a C++ 98 compiler, so I can't use the string move functionality!

If you need anymore information, let me know.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If that line doesn't cause the segfault and the call to `find` does, why do you tell us that that line does? I wouldn't say the location is irrelevant. Can you show us `find`?

Comment: Also 'inc_frequency()' and 'insert()', as 'find()' should not modify any data to cause segfault and since 'data()' fires the segfault, something has been wrongly modified before I think.

Comment: I didn't include find() because it makes the same function call. I know it seg faults in both places, and in gdb as well.

Comment: @Tolga @ @sftrabbit Find doesn't modify data, but it calls the HeapNode `data()` function which is where the program seg faults. When `data()` returns `datafield`, there is a seg fault. Based on testing, it doesn't matter where `data()` is called from. It is also worth noting, in case it was looked over in the original question, the function returns normally if `datafield` is any type except a `string`